# listing file in unix and saving the output in a variable(Oldest File fetching for a particular extension)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

This might be a very simple thing for a shell scripting programmer but am pretty new to it. I was trying to execute the below command in a shell script and save the output into a variable

```
inputfile=$(ls -ltr *.{PDF,pdf} | head -1 | awk '{print $9}')
```

The command works fine when I fire it from terminal but fails when executed through a shell script (sh). Why is that the command fails, does it mean that shell script doesn't support the command or am I doing it wrong? Also how do I know if a command will work in shell or not?

Just to give you a glimpse of my requirement, I was trying to get the oldest file from a particular directory (I also want to make sure upper case and lower case extensions are handled). Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: In single quote you calling $9 try: inputfile=$(ls -ltr *.{PDF,pdf} | head -1 | awk '{print '"$9"'}') you can try whitout double quote

Comment: ensure your script is running in the dir with the .PDF files by adding an `echo "#Dbg : pwd=$PWD"` just before your `inputfile=...` cmd.  If not, then add a `cd /path/dir/with/PDFfiles` before. Good luck.

Comment: @Noproblem : I believe the issue is with the {pdf,PDF} , The script is not fails saying cannot find the command . I will try your suggestion for sure but am still confused why is that happening.

Comment: @shellter : The script has a CD command just before the command so as to navigate to the folder(I missed to mention that). As i mentioned above the script is not able to read the {pdf,PDF} (Globbing).

Comment: OK. How about this. "Explode" your pipeline putting just `ls -ltr *.{PDF,pdf}` on one line, then the next line would include `ls ... | head -1`; and finally `ls .. | head .. | awk ...` to see which part is failing. There's nothing obvious in your code that should be a problem, except for a `PATH` failure for `awk` that could be causing this, so you have to dig in and see where the problem is coming from. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The above command will work correctly only if BOTH `*.pdf` and `*.PDF` files are in the directory you are currently.
If you would like to execute it in a directory with only one of those you should consider using e.g.:

```
inputfiles=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.pdf" -or -name "*.PDF" \) | xargs ls -1tr | head -1 )
```

*NOTE*: The above command doesn't work with files with new lines, or with long list of found files.

Comment: `-and` is useless. Maybe you want `-iname '*.pdf'`. You don't need (and don't want) to pass the `-l` argument to `ls`: it's useless, broken (as it's not consistent across platforms), and you need to strip all that out with `awk` which is broken as it will break filenames containing spaces. Now, if there are really a lot of files (more than the allowed maximum number of arguments), this might be broken since `xargs` will call `ls` several time. Finally, weird results will occur if there happens to be a directory ending in `pdf` or `PDF`.

Comment: And I'm not even mentioning newlines in filenames. And I'm not even mentioning that `xargs` will break if there are quotes in filenames.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm just fixing the problem that the author had, you can write a comment to him. He wanted PDF and pdf files, iname will allow also PdF, or pdF. I agree with your other remarks, I just created a quick fix for the comment without much complication added (like newlines or spaces in the filenames).

Comment: If you spend time answering the question, you should address all the other issues too! because your answer is going to stay online forever, for future generations to see it and learn from it! do you want them to see `ls -l | awk '{print $9}'` which is broken? do you want them to see all the other issues?

Comment: @krzyk : Thanks for the help :) . Shouldn't maxdepth come before type ?

Comment: @Garfield Yes, I added it, but forgot to test it. I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is always a bad idea. You need another strategy.

How about you make a function that gives you the oldest file among the ones given as argument? the following works in Bash (adapt to your needs):

```
get_oldest_file() {
   # get oldest file among files given as parameters
   # return is in variable get_oldest_file_ret
   local oldest f
   for f do
      [[ -e $f ]] && [[ ! $oldest || $f -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$f
   done
   get_oldest_file_ret=$oldest
}
```

Then just call as:

```
get_oldest_file *.{PDF,pdf}
echo "oldest file is: $get_oldest_file_ret"
```

Now, you probably don't want to use brace expansions like this at all. In fact, you very likely want to use the shell options `nocaseglob` and `nullglob`:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob
get_oldest_file *.pdf
echo "oldest file is: $get_oldest_file_ret"
```

If you're using a POSIX shell, it's going to be a bit trickier to have the equivalent of `nullglob` and `nocaseglob`.

Comment: Can you use `get_oldest_file *.pdf *.PDF` in a POSIX shell ?

Comment: @WalterA yeah, it'll work… but in a strictly POSIX shell you'll have to slightly rewrite the function too.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : Thanks , this will also get me the stuffs done. I believe the code that you have put up is for bash and not sh, i mean if i run it as sh scriptname.sh , the script will fail with syntax error right.Correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: You're correct, this is Bash code (but you tagged your question so). There are a few adjustments to make in order to make it work in strict POSIX shells. But, if you can, I'd recommend you use Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Is `perl` an option? It's ubiquitous on Unix.

I would suggest:

```
perl -e 'print ((sort { -M $b <=> -M $a } glob ( "*.{pdf,PDF}" ))[0]);';
```

Which:

- uses `glob` to fetch all files matching the pattern.
- sort, using `-M` which is relative modification time. (in days).
- fetches the first element (`[0]`) off the sort.
- Prints that.

Answer (score 0):

As @gniourf_gniourf says, parsing ls is a bad idea.  Such as leaving unquoted globs, and generally not counting for funny characters in file names.

find is your friend:

```
#!/bin/sh
get_oldest_pdf() {
    #
    # echo path of oldest *.pdf (case-insensitive) file in current directory
    #
    find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -iname "*.pdf" -printf '%T@ %p\n' \
      | sort -n \
      | tail -1 \
      | cut -d\   -f1-
}
whatever=$(get_oldest_pdf)
```

Notes:

- `find` has numerous ways of formatting the output, including
  things like access time and/or write time.  I used `'%T@ %p\n'`,
  where `%T@` is last write time in UNIX time format incl.fractal part.
  This will never containt space so it's safe to use as separator.
- Numeric sort and tail get the last item, sorting by the time,
- *cut* removes the time from the output.
- I used IMO much easier to read/maintain pipe notation, with help of `\`.
- the code should run on any POSIX shell,
- You could easily adjust the function to parametrize the pattern,
  time used (access/write), control the search depth or starting dir.