# ksh script to keep 7 files in a directory and move the oldest file every time it receives the 8th file

Tags: ftp, ksh, aix

need help to write script in ksh that basically in a directory there will be transfer each day one file, but in this directory (carpet) there most not be more than 7 files (one file weekly transfer) in csv format. so the script should just keep 7 files and when it receives the 8th file, it should move the oldest (.csv file) to another server, I know how to script the ftp but dont know how to write this kind of script and put this type of script in a cron job to run on the 8th day. for example every monday at 1am. Thanks hope some help. I type this but not sure if it could work.

```
find /successfactors/interfaces/OUT -mtime +8 -type f -exec mv "{}" /successfactors/interfaces/out-resp \;
```

Comment: When you get exactly one file each day this looks ok. When you need to count your files, you will need something like [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33333103/3220113](get_oldest_file()). When you have files without spaces or newlines, you can ignore the general advise to avoid parsing `ls -t`.

Comment: thanks walter let me check that link, yeah in fact maybe they will upload more than 1 file a day

Comment: Can you explain why are you creating this in regards to SuccessFactors?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no security breach about file name (you control file name) or special file name (like non ascii char or control char)

```
ls -1t \
 | sed -n '1,7 !p' \
 | while read FileName
    do
      # ftp your file "${FileName}" 

      rm "${FileName}"
    done
```

but it is maybe more secure to ftp incoming file instead of only older file